# Read and write to the same CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with Name and Status columns. We need to read the Name from the CSV file and perform a set of action on that, once we finish the action on one Name we need to update the status of that Name as 'Completed' on the same  .csv file.

```
Name        Status
poc_dev_admin   
poc_dev_qa  
poc_dev_qa1 
poc_dev_qa2 
poc_dev_qa3 
poc_dev_qa7 
poc_dev_qa8 
poc_dev_ro  
poc_dev_support 
poc_dev_test1   
poc_dev_test14  
poc_dev_test15  
poc_dev_test16
```

After execution of `poc_dev_admin` the CSV file should be like the following:

```
Name    Status
poc_dev_admin   Completed
poc_dev_qa  
poc_dev_qa1 
poc_dev_qa2 
poc_dev_qa3 
poc_dev_qa7 
poc_dev_qa8 
poc_dev_ro  
poc_dev_support 
poc_dev_test1   
poc_dev_test14  
poc_dev_test15  
poc_dev_test16
```

I have tried with this logic and it updates Status column for all groups rather than updating it after processing the respective group. May I what change should we make to work this as expected?

```
$P = Import-Csv -Path c:\test\abintm.csv
foreach ($groupname in $P) {
    ### Process $groupname####
    $newprocessstatus = 'Completed'  
    $P | Select-Object *, @{n='Status';e={$newprocessstatus}} |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\test\abintm.csv    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "after execution of poc_dev_admin"? Do you only want to update the status of records with a particular name? What are your criteria?

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers, my requirement is to update the Status column of each group name once we complete the processing of that respective group. ie when we complete 'poc_dev_admin'   status column corresponding to that group should be updated as 'Completed' and once we complete 'poc_dev_qa ' the status column of the same should be updated as 'Completed' and so on and so forth for other groups as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for what you described:

```
$file = 'c:\test\abintm.csv'

$csv = Import-Csv $file

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $groupname = $row.Name
    # ...
    # process $groupname
    # ...
    $row.Status = 'Completed'
}

$csv | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

If you need to update the CSV before processing the next record you can put the CSV export at the end of the loop (right after setting `$row.Status` to "Completed").

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code for the use case you've specified,

1. Changed current item variable in foreach loop to `$row` instead of `$groupname`
2. However, defined the `$groupname` variable inside the foreach block

```
$List = Import-Csv -Path "c:\test\abintm.csv"


foreach ($row in $List) {

    $groupName = $row.Name
    $status = $row.Status

    if ($groupName -eq "poc_dev_admin") {
        $status = "Completed"
        ($List | ? { $_.Name -eq $groupName }).Status = $status
    }

}

if (($List | ? { $_.Status -eq "Completed" }) -ne $null) {
    # $List has been modifed and hence write back the updated $List to the csv file
    $List | Export-Csv -Notypeinformation -Path "C:\test\abintm.csv"
}
# else nothing is written
```

Comment: Let me check, my requirement is to update each and every group's status column once processing of the same group is done as 'Completed'

Comment: In your question, you had asked for the specific group 'poc_dev_admin' and hence I've tailored my answer relative to the same. If the condition varies, you may want to add the `-or` operator to the `if` statement based on your requirement.